# When I create a component and add the routing it says component is missing. What can I do?

Tags: php, html, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am creating an eCommerce site lin Laravel8 using Livewire.
When I create the component(DetailsComponent) and view file(details-component.blade.php) and add the routes it says

> `DetailsComponent` was not found: Controller class `DetailsComponent` for one of your routes was not found. Are you sure this controller exists and is imported correctly?

This is the route I used.

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}', DetailsComponent ::class)->name('product.details');
```

This is the DetailsComponent

```
<?PHP
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class DetailsComponent extends Component
 {
   public $slug;

   public function mount($slug)
   {
      $this-> slug = $slug;
   }

   public function render()
   {
     $product = Product:: where('slug', $this->slug)->first();
     return view('livewire.details-component',['product'=> $product])->layout("layouts.base") ;
   }
}
```

This is the error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8ecommerce>php artisan serve
UnexpectedValueException

Invalid route action: [DetailsComponent].

at 
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:92
   88▕      */
   89▕     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
   90▕     {
   91▕         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
➜ 92▕             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
   93▕         }
   94▕
   95▕         return $action.'@__invoke';
   96▕     }

  `DetailsComponent` was not found: Controller class `DetailsComponent` for one of your routes was not found. Are you sure this controller exists and is imported correctly?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the top of your file where you execute `Route::get('/product/{slug}', DetailsComponent ::class)->name('product.details');`? (Im interested only in the lines which start with `namespace` and/or `use`).

Comment: I think its an issue with the import, can you update the question with the top of your `web.php` file, And is the component located in Another subdirectory under `App\Http\Livewire`

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal both of you were right. I haven't put the " use App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent;" in the web.php.. my mistake

Comment: @Irfan both of you were right. I haven't put the " use App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent;" in the web.php.. my mistake